# Confused why the writer used fixed instead of fix

Tags: present-perfect

Confused why the writer used fixed instead of fix

Here are the examples:

Let's get this **fixed**," and you pay for the repair again.

"We've got to get this **fixed** right now," Ryan said.

Since the item has not been returned to it's original state, why are they using the term **fixed**?
The only reason i see the writer used **fixed** is because of present perfect.
**Get** is present tense and **fixed** is past tense. But i just cant seem to wrap my head around it.  Can anyone help me out.

Comment: "Fixed" is an adjective here, not a verb. Compare with "Let's paint this green".

Comment: In this context _get_ is a causative verb, synonymous with but more informal than _have_. Here is information about causatives _get_ and _have_: https://www.perfect-english-grammar.com/causatives-have-get.html

Answer (score 4):

"Get + past participle" is one way of forming the passive in English.

Used intransitively, it is a simple passive ("The cake got eaten").

Used with an object in this way, it is a passive causative ("cause something to have something be done to it"). The past participle is invariable, and does not change whatever the tense:

> We got that fixed.
>
> We'll get that fixed.
>
> We're getting that fixed.
>
> We would have got that fixed. ("gotten" in American English, I believe.)

Answer (score 0):

> Let's get this fixed.

In this example, "fixed" has no tense.   "Get" has no tense.   The only verb with tense is "let".

This "let" is in the imperative mode, present tense, active voice and indefinite aspect.   It forms a predicate that takes an implicit second-person subject.   It licenses a direct object and an object complement.   The object is a contracted "us", and the complement is the infinitive phrase "[to] get this fixed".

The verb *to let* licenses bare infinitive object complements.   Other verbs license full infinitives for that same role, such as:

> Allow us **to get** this fixed.

or

> We've got **to get** this fixed.

The verb *to get* also licenses direct objects and object complements.   In these examples, the demonstrative pronoun "this" serves as the object and the participle "fixed" serves as the complement.

Most verbs have past-tense forms and so-called past-participle forms that are identical.   A few, such as *to do*, have distinct forms:

> *We've got to get this did. 
>     We've got to get this done.

The past-tense form "did" does not work here.   The participle form "done", on the other hand, is a suitable candidate for an object complement licensed by the verb *to get*.

You're looking for tense where tense does not exist.   The "fixed" of your original and the "done" of my clarifying example are both non-finite forms.   They are participles in an attributive role, modifying a direct object through a governing verb's license.   The instances of "get" in these examples are also non-finite forms.   They are infinitives in a substantive role, acting as the objects of their governing verbs.